# Java, encoding with my custom cipher

Tags: java, encryption, memory-management

I have a program that encode and decodes with my custom cipher, text files and lossless media files, but the problem is that over 2MB it crashes.

```
void doTheRabi(File f, byte[] hashedPass) {
    try {
        // BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new
        // FileInputStream(f))); // legge il file
        // String response = new
        // String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(f.getAbsolutePath()))); // scrive tutto
        // il file in memoria
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(f);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        String response = new String(); // ASSEGNO IL CONTENUTO DEL FILE IN QUESTA STRINGA
        for (String line; (line = br.readLine()) != null; response += line + "\n")
            ;
        response = response.replace("\n", "newline").replace("\r", "newrow"); // rimpiazzo le new line con "newline"
                                                                                // e "newrow"
        byte[] encodedfile = response.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8); // trasformo il file in byte
        byte[] result = new byte[encodedfile.length]; // variabile temporanea
        int hpc = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
            result[i] = (byte) (encodedfile[i] + hashedPass[hpc++]); // algoritmo rabi
            if (hpc == hashedPass.length) {
                hpc = 0;
            }
        }
        String encodedresult = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(result); // restituisco il risultato in base64
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(f);
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fw);
        pw.print("");
        pw.append(encodedresult /* + "extension=" + extString */); // scrivo nel file tutto il risultato
        pw.flush();
        pw.close();
        fw.close();
        br.close();
        String path = f.getAbsolutePath();
        String newName = path + ".rab1";
        f.renameTo(new File(newName));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        console.appendText("Error: " + e.getMessage() + "\n");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

// operazione inversa
void killTheRabi(File f, byte[] hashedPass) {
    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(f)));
        String response = new String();
        for (String line; (line = br.readLine()) != null; response += line)
            ;
        byte[] decodedfile = Base64.getDecoder().decode(response);
        byte[] result = new byte[decodedfile.length];
        int hpc = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
            result[i] = (byte) (decodedfile[i] - hashedPass[hpc++]);
            if (hpc == hashedPass.length) {
                hpc = 0;
            }
        }
        String resultString = bytesToString(result);
        String finalres = resultString.replace("newline", "\n").replace("newrow", "\r");
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(f);
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fw);
        pw.print("");
        pw.append(finalres);
        pw.flush();
        pw.close();
        fw.close();
        br.close();
        String path = f.getAbsolutePath();
        String newName = path.replace(".rab1", "");
        f.renameTo(new File(newName));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        console.appendText("Error: " + e.getMessage() + "\n");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? I think it's because the memory gets full, since java uses a virtual machine, but I don't know a way to enhance the memory usage, maybe using buffers but am I not using them already?

Comment: what error message do you get?

Comment: it just freezes

Comment: that is not necessaryily an error. it might very well be your code is still processing your data, that's a different matter

Comment: Don't keep everything in memory, you can work on one block after the other. And your method to assemble the string `response` is extremely inefficient. Learn how to use a `StringBuilder`.

Comment: You need to make `response` a `StringBuilder` rather than a `String`.

Comment: String is fine for static values, but a StringBuilder should be more efficient in your case.

Comment: Ok I'm using a stringbuilder, but it freezes on the decoding, how should I decode the stringbuilder? if I use stringbuilder.toString() it puts everything back in memory

Comment: Why do you concatenate all line `String`s using `\n` as separator, just to perform `replace("\n", "newline").replace("\r", "newrow")` afterwards? You can use `"newline"` in the first place. And what Java version are you using? What about [`Files.readAllLines`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllLines(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.charset.Charset)) and [`Files.write`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#write(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.lang.Iterable,%20java.nio.charset.Charset,%20java.nio.file.OpenOption...))?

Comment: By the way, you are creating a writer for the same file as you’ve read, before the reader has been closed. That is not guaranteed to work. And it’s really strange, as you are renaming the file afterwards, indicating that the output location is supposed to be different, so why don’t you write to the intended target location (`new File(newName)`) right from the start?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are possibly holding quite a bit of data in memory, try the following:
Increase maximum heap size to be used by the JVM by starting with the parameter -Xmx2048m or more